# Can't read files from SDcard folder in Android device?

Tags: java, android, android-listview, whatsapp

I am trying to access `WhatsApp` database folder exists in `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + /WhatsApp/Databases` location in un-rooted device.

My aim is to collect these files and decrypt them and show each messages to `Web portal`. Here is the code to collect these files:

```
 String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + location;
 f = new File(path);
 final File file[]=f.listFiles();
 final int size = file.length;
```

Whenever i am running on rooted device, `It is working` but on some unrooted devices it is throwing `nullpointer` because it is not able to get the list of all database files.

My question is: Is it possible to ready `WhatsApp Database` files when device is not root?
or is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure the **root** effects. Have you get the PERMISSION for your app ? if not, you can try to put `uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` on your manifest and then test it.

Comment: I also think that root is not affecting this APP because it worked on `Samsung` device but not on `Nexus` and `motog`

Answer (score 0):

you are able to read database file try below code its worked if device is not rooted.

i have tried these in **Samsung Grand 2**, **HTC**

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "/WhatsApp/Databases";
        File file = new File(path);
        if (file.exists()) {
            File[] filenames = file.listFiles();
            for (File tmpf : filenames) {
                // Do something with the files
                if (tmpf.isFile()) {
                    Log.e("tmpf-------->", "not add---->" + tmpf.getPath());
                }
            }

        } else {
            Log.e("folder not found", "folder not found");
        }
```

[image]

don't forget to add permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score -2):

No, You can't get SQLite databse file from an Android device if it's not rooted, since you have no permission to access data folder.

But yes you can get database if you run app on emulator.

Comment: Is it possible make root for only this app?